# Ubuntu suddenly became very slow

Tags: cpu

I have two operating systems: Ubuntu and Linux Mint.

I usually do programming on the first one and today I turned the computer on and after some time (about 1 minute), Ubuntu suddenly started to be very slow. I could barely move the cursor and the command that I run was executing endlessly. I shut down the computer, log in to Ubuntu again and again the same issue - after some time it became very slow. This time I did Ctrl + Alt + F1 and run the "top" command (which took me ages), there were no process that was slowing it down. "top" command itself was the most consuming process.

After that I shut down the computer, logged in to Linux Mint (which works perfectly fine and doesn't slow down), I googled a bit on how to solve this problem but didn't find anything that would help me and now I'm writing this question.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have no idea how to even start to look for what might be wrong. What should I check? How to fix this?

At the beginning I thought it might be overheating problem, but Linux Mint works fine, so it shouldn't be that, should it?

Update:

I realised now that when I'm on Linux Mint, it slows down and almost freezes too. It just happens after longer time of using it.

Comment: I would start with a hardware check (is hdd/ssd health?, ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools as other OSes are usually in different partitions or other places on the disk, and thus may not experience problems for a dying drive etc... This would be performed on a 'live' environment so disk isn't being used.. Next depending on the box I'd do some checks of the hardware   If hardware looks okay, I'd login to runlevel 1 only, and scan logs hoping I'd find clues etc...  Where I went may vary on box details, environment etc.. but general hardware is my thinking..

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start the `Disks` application, select your disk, go to the "hamburger" icon and select SMART Data & Tests. Take screenshot(s) of the scrollable Data window, and edit them into your question, or load them at imgur.com for me to look at. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.